# How to make watermarks on videos easy on the user but harder to get rid of?

Tags: video

I have friends that make small content for Youtube that they find ends up being stolen on other social media sites, uploaded on different usernames, and the watermarks removed secretly.  Typically the watermarks he puts on the videos are placed on the lower left, so the videos being copied end up being zoomed in slightly to remove the watermark or just blurred out entirely.

How can he, as a content creator, be better able to provide watermarks on videos that would be a lot harder for thieves to steal and reupload, at the same time making it easier on people watching the videos themselves?

For example, he had asked me, and initially I thought you can have the watermarked logo swirling around the screen slowly, that way making it harder for people to "blur" it out, as they'd need to do it frame by frame. Then I realized it wasn't a very good idea as it would heavily distract a regular user from watching the content and thus be of no good to anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rarely does a design or technology solution to intellectual properly legal issues make things better for the user. Be it watermarks or copy protection, the user experience is compromised.

So the question is how much does your friend want to compromise the UX in exchange for making things slightly more difficult for his audience? Only your friend can answer that, of course.